# Clearing out a FileManager.SearchPathDirectory

Tags: ios, swift3, nsfilemanager

What is the easiest way of deleting every file in a SearchPathDirectory for example the

> documentDirectory

If I was working with a directory inside one of the directories I would simply delete the folder and re-add it but I can't remove one of these directories.

Comment: I don't think iOS makes use of `picturesDirectory`. That's for macOS. Many of the SearchPathDirectory values have no use in iOS.

Comment: Bad example then. Lets say documentDirectory instead